# ExecuteNonQuery silently failed without any errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

**UPDATE**: my code is behaving as expected by there was a typo in the stored procedure that was the reason it was failing.

---

I can't seem to figure out why or how to fix this because I am not getting any errors what I am getting is the return value is 0 which means fail.

Here is my .net code:

```
SqlParameter returnValue= new SqlParameter("returnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

result = Convert.ToInt32(returnValue.Value); //1 success and 0 failed
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeUpdate
    @employee_id BIGINT,
    @name nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @Result int  
    SET @Result = 0  

    UPDATE Employee
    SET name = @name 
    WHERE employee_id = @employee_id                   

    IF (@@rowcount = 1) 
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1       
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    RETURN @Result 
END
```

So if I just execute the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio, it does update my row successfully without any error

```
EXEC EmployeeUpdate 34,'John John'

Return Value = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to remove returnValue parameter altogether and just use the return value of ExecuteNonQuery() method instead:

```
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

result = rowsAffected == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeUpdate
       @employee_id BIGINT,
       @name nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN 
      UPDATE Employee
      SET  name = @name 
      WHERE  employee_id = @employee_id                   
END
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers on that table that might cause a rollback? What do you get in SQL Management Studio if you run the simplified version of the stored procedure above? i.e. EXEC EmployeeUpdate 34,'John John'

Comment: dont have any triggers on table just double check that.

Comment: i get the return value = 1 and when i checked the table and i see my updated values

Comment: You need to run "simplified" sp from my answer - i.e. without SET NOCOUNT ON line. That's what causing ExecuteNonQuery() to return -1 in your case.

Comment: but i am doing `set nocount` off before it `returns` i will give it a shot and see

Comment: What do you mean by returnvalue = 0? Are you saying you're using the "simplified" sp from my answer AND your row gets updated in the database but you're not getting rowsAffected == 1? I just tested it on AdventureWorks database and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeUpdate
       @employee_id BIGINT,
       @name nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN 
      SET NOCOUNT ON
```

With Following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeUpdate
       @employee_id BIGINT,
       @name nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN 
      SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

---

> SET NOCOUNT ON is indicating that number of rows effect by T-SQL will
> not be returned
>
> SET NOCOUNT OFF mean that number of rows effect by
> T-SQL will be returned.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there any other way to debug?

Comment: Yes, You have an another way. Please go to the `database`. Now, execute the `Stored-Proc` in the `SSMS`. Like this, `EmployeeUpdate 1, 'PankajGarg'`. Here it can be checked what is the actual result being returned using `Set NOCount ON/OFF`